# Crows-foot notation in an Sqlite database model

Tags: sqlite, database-design, entity-relationship

I'm getting to grips with using 'crows-foot' notation to design Sqlite databases using Navicat. In a book chapter designed to get users up and running with this software I have come across the following example, consisting of an ER diagram and some explanatory text:

*There is a many-to-one relationship between the category table and the task table. In our case, a task can have one category associated with it, but a category can have many tasks under it. As such, a task can be assigned to one user, but a user can have many tasks.*
[image]

I was surprised to read this because the notation seems to be at odds with the description. My way of reading these diagrams (arrived at by examining various freely available examples on the internet) is to start with the table (say **Task**) then look at the notation that is 'attached' to the related table (in this case 'one or more') and construct the relationship as follows: **Task** belongs to '*one or more*' **Categories**. Such a relationship is possible of course, but it seems inconsistent with the verbal description of the desired relationship, namely: '*a task can have one category associated with it*'. Am I misunderstanding crow's-foot notation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ERD (whether using Crow's foot or Chen notation) the "many" side has always the foreign key, The Task table has the foreign key Category_id and therefore is on the "many" side while Category has the related primary key named ID and therefore is on the "one" side. So, you're right in your interpretation actually.